# add order comment in order pdf

Tags: magento2.3, sales-order

im work on print order to print order comment when we do print order from front end,

**My Orders->Print Order**

when click on Print Order the same comment print on PDF,
for that i have created Module using override core files

registration.php, module.xml

Here is a code,

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Tms\Printcomment\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

**Tms\Printcomment\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php**

**app/code/Tms/Printcomment/view/frontend/templates/order/order_comments.phtml**

```
<?php $_history = $block->getOrder()->getVisibleStatusHistory() ?>
<?php if (!empty($_history)) : ?>
    <div class="block block-order-details-comments">
        <div class="block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('About Your Order')) ?></strong></div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <dl class="order-comments">
                <?php foreach ($_history as $_historyItem) : ?>
                    <dt class="comment-date">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */
                        $block->formatDate($_historyItem->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, true) ?>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="comment-content"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_historyItem->getComment()) ?></dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**app/code/Tms/Printcomment/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print.xml**

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- <referenceBlock name="additional.product.info"> 
            <block class="Tms\Printcomment\Order\View" 
                name="order.comments"
                template="Namespace_Sales::order/order_comments.phtml" 
               cacheable="false" /> 
         </referenceBlock> -->
        <!-- <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="order.comments" template="Magento_Sales::order/order_comments.phtml" />-->
        <referenceBlock name="order.comments" template="Tms_Printcomment::order/order_comments.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

But its not work, comment not print in PDF, what shoud I do wrong? please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can create an extension. because you need to override files.
First create file `app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
```

Now override file `app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\ Invoice.php`
in function `getPdf()`
use code

```
foreach ($invoice->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status){
            $textChunk = wordwrap(strip_tags($status->getComment()), 120, "\n");
            foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
                if ($textLine!=='') {
                    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                    $this->y -= 15;
                }
            }
        }
```

For adding custom template to any block
 follow

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order.comments">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::order/comments/view.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: i update my Question with New Code...but its not work can u plesase suggest me what mistakes i do? Override file is not working

Comment: You need to add code in the file which you are using for printing PDF. like this app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Rewrite\Order\Pdf\Invoice.pdf

Comment: that is ok, file is on the right place, but whole module not work

Comment: core file is not override. i have done any mistakes?

Comment: you are taking reference in wrong way

Comment: for which reference? core file override?

Comment: can i send u my module's zip?

Comment: if reference is not working the pls try with the code I have added. send me zip

Comment: how can i sendd u module zip to u

Comment: i have send u module

Comment: Thanks Kamal Mittal for your help

Comment: using this extension Can we add comment on email template?

Comment: you can simply get comments in the email template file from the function which we have used in the file.

Comment: {{depend order.getComment()}}
    <p>{{var order.getComment() |raw}}</p>
  {{/depend}}

Comment: i use above code in template but its not wirk

Comment: {{var order.getComments()}} its also not work

Comment: {{depend order.getComment()}}
    <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
        Order Comment: {{htmlescape var=$order.getComment()}}
    </p>
{{/depend}}

Comment: For that you need to add the content in the phtml file which you are using to show the order items.
OR you can override the order file to add an extra variable (order_comment) for email template then you can show the comments easily.